# C# - external table is not in the expected format excel error for xls file

Tags: c#, excel, connection-string, xls

I am creating an excel file and import data to excel file. And then  I am reading this file. But my app gives "external table is not in the expected format excel" error on "excelConnection.Open();" line.

My connection string is below for xls file :

```
 excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileLocation + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0; HDR = Yes; IMEX = 1'";
```

This works for xlsx file : `excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileLocation + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";`

Comment: you have given the correct string at the bottom. Why aren't you using at the top?

Comment: The bottom string doesn't work for xls files. It works for only xlsx files.

Comment: Apologies, I missed the missing x

Comment: Have you tried OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=yourSource;
Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1";

Comment: It gives an error like : An OLE DB Provider was not specified in the ConnectionString. An example would be, 'Provider=SQLOLEDB;

Comment: maybe have a look at these https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/